# Найти количество целочисленных точек внутри круга x^2+y^2=n^2, где n - целое число, вводимое пользователем

Tags: pascal, блок-схема

Вот код программы, помогите составить блок схему для данной программы

```
 var n,x,y,k:integer;
    begin
    write('введите n=');
    readln(n);
    k:=0;
      for x:=-n to n do
      for y:=-n to n do
        if x*x+y*y<=n*n then 
      k:=k+1;
       writeln('k=',k);
     readln;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот сделал блок-схему. Забирайте.

[image: блок-схема]